# Android: Linking ViewFlipper to TextView

Tags: android, textview, viewflipper

With help from this link: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634, I created a successful flipper that displays eight images. Here's part of my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.analysis);
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.Flipper);
    vs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSpecies);

    for (int i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(imagesArray[i]);
        vf.addView(imageView);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++) {
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setBackgroundResource(stringsArray[i]);
        vs.addView(textview);
    }
```

Now what I'm trying to do is attach a TextView to each image that will show up with its respective picture when the flipper is set on that picture. This is my attempt:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringsArray.length; i++) {
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setBackgroundResource(stringsArray[i]);
        vs.addView(textview);
    }
```

I added a for loop underneath the first, but this creates errors in the last two lines. I don't want the text to be a part of the flipper, but rather, on top of it. 
How would I proceed?

Comment: Why not create a layout with an imageview and a textview and then flip between those layouts?

Comment: I'm trying to create an application where the top of the screen shows a picture and the bottom contains the flipper. A person would flip through the pictures in the flipper until they find the one that matches with the picture on top. I'd like each picture in the flipper to have a textview that can be saved into a database. @AleksG

Comment: I repeat, instead of flipping the pictures, flip layouts containing a picture and a textview

Comment: You can't add views to a `TextView` like `vs.addView(textview);`. Like Aleks G already pointed out you should put the `TextView` and the `ImageView` in a layout and add that as a page of the `ViewFlipper`.